# Asp.net .aspx and MVC Co-existing project, the Codebehind/Codefile still existing inside .aspx files after project published

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, publishing

We have Asp.net .aspx and MVC Co-existing project,   Codebehind/Codefile are still existing inside .aspx files after project published, it needes a lot of effort to get rid of these after deployment:
we have to manually change every .aspx file

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/xxx.master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="xxx.Login" Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" %>
```

To

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/xxx.master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="xxx.Login"  %>
```

it is ton of work to do that
anyone can help?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure I fully understand... If you are using Visual Studio's Publish feature and have selected "only files needed to run this app", your code-behind files should not be deployed.

Comment: the 
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/xxx.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="xxx.Login" Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" %>

Codebehind attribute of Page was not taken off from .ASPX files after deployed

Comment: I've seen the same thing - everything works if I remove the CodeFile attribute after deploying, otherwise the page request fails because the .CS file is missing.  I don't have a solution yet, though :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the **Codebehind** attribute from your ASPX files.
You just deploy them without .CS files.
The classes specified in the Codebehind are compiled in to the assembly and are available after the assembly gets deployed (which you do always).

Comment: if the codebehind/codefile attribute not been removed, the web page generated an error when request to the page, after manually remove it, it works, so this attribute should be remvoed somehow.

Thanks
Simon